# ODOO12: not creating db column?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I having a problem with ODOO 12, I am declaring a text field and it is simply not being created by ODOO, I have already enabled --log-level debug_sql, and at creation time it just skips the field without giving me any errors...

My code:

```
class Processo(models.Model): 

    _name = 'processo'
    _description = 'Processo'


    name = fields.Char(string='Número do processo', readonly=True)

    status = fields.Selection(selection=[
                ('tec','Análise Técnica'),            
                ('tecsup','Análise Técnica Superior'),
                ('pendencia','Pendência'),            
                ('indeferido','Indeferido'),            
                ('concluido','Concluído')],        
                string='Estados',        
                default='tec')    

    is_tecsup = fields.Boolean( string='É análise superior?')

    requerente_id = fields.Many2one( string='Requerente', comodel_name='res.partner', readonly=True)​

    requerente_user_id = fields.Many2one( string='Requerente', comodel_name='res.users', readonly=True)

    documentos_ids = fields.One2many(string='Documentos', comodel_name='documentos.protocolos', inverse_name='processo_id')    

    protocolo_ids = fields.One2many( comodel_name='protocolo', inverse_name='processo_id', string='Protocolos')    

    protocolo_id = fields.Many2one( comodel_name='protocolo', string='Protocolo')

    data_aprovacao = fields.Date(string="Data do alvará")    

    historico = fields.Text( string="Histórico")    

    pendencia_processo = fields.Text(string="TEST")​

    pendencia = fields.Text(string="Pendencia") # <= field problem
```

This is the log at creation time:

> 2019-11-27 13:28:32,156 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "name" VARCHAR
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,182 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."name" IS 'Número do processo'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,182 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: SELECT 1 FROM "processo" LIMIT 1
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,183 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_name_index"
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,183 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "status" VARCHAR
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,184 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."status" IS 'Estados'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,184 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_status_index"
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,184 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "is_tecsup" bool
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,185 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."is_tecsup" IS 'É análise superior?'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,185 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_is_tecsup_index"
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,186 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "requerente_id" int4
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,186 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."requerente_id" IS 'Requerente'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,187 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_requerente_id_index"
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,187 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "requerente_user_id" int4
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,187 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."requerente_user_id" IS 'Requerente'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,188 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_requerente_user_id_index"
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,188 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "protocolo_id" int4
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,189 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."protocolo_id" IS 'Protocolo'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,189 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_protocolo_id_index"
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,191 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "data_aprovacao" date
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,191 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."data_aprovacao" IS 'Data do alvará'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,191 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_data_aprovacao_index"
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,191 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "historico" text
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,192 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."historico" IS 'Histórico'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,192 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_historico_index"
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,192 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "pendencia_processo" text
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,192 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."pendencia_processo" IS 'TEST'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,193 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_pendencia_processo_index"
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,193 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "autorizador_id" int4
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,193 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."autorizador_id" IS 'Autorizador'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,193 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_autorizador_id_index"
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,194 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "create_uid" int4
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,194 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."create_uid" IS 'Created by'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,194 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_create_uid_index"
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,194 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "create_date" timestamp
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,194 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."create_date" IS 'Created on'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,195 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_create_date_index"
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,195 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "write_uid" int4
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,195 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."write_uid" IS 'Last Updated by'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,195 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_write_uid_index"
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,196 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: ALTER TABLE "processo" ADD COLUMN "write_date" timestamp
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,196 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: COMMENT ON COLUMN "processo"."write_date" IS 'Last Updated on'
>   2019-11-27 13:28:32,196 24061 DEBUG teste_all odoo.sql_db: query: DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "processo_write_date_index"118/5000

Simply skips field "pendencia" creation without giving me any errors ... Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Can you try to change string name for "pendencia_processo" and pendencia as both are same as "Pendencia"

Comment: Changed, pendencia_processo now has the string "TEST"

Comment: I changed the string and still the same. I even have created another db to test it

Comment: "pendencia" is the key of one of your selection field key i.e. "status" field. Try to modify key in that selection field and check again.

Comment: @KevalMehta That can't be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume your Odoo does not see the same version of the file you are modifying. In debug log you have field ”Autorizador” after ”Pendencia processo”, not ”Pendencia” like in your source.

Make sure Odoo loads the latest version of your module by reinstalling it and restarting Odoo server.

Also check that you have only one version of the file and Odoo is using that. You can check this with debug statements in your code like this:

```
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Processo(models.Model): 

    _name = 'processo'
    _description = 'Processo'

    _logger.debug("Your code was executed. ")
    #...rest of your code here.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not see the same version of the file"?

Comment: If you either have multiple instances of your Odoo module, or Odoo does not somehow reload your changed files. In your logs you have log entries for field "Autorizador" that you do not have in your source, at least not the version of source your provided. Sometimes I have had situations where Odoo does not refresh the modules correctly. Most of the times restarting Odoo or removing/reinstalling module helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only way I found to solve this was reinstalling the module, upgrading just doesn't work... If I upgrade the module the field dont appear anywhere and If I try to restart the server, I just get the error  _psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column *** does not exist_ I just gave up.